# Drawing Manager circle moves when zoom out

Tags: react

I am using DrawingManager to draw a circle at zoom level 19.

```
this.drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE);
```

[image]

when zoomed out the circle is moving. Now the circle is in the intersection.

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the circle _seems_ to move only because the displayed width of the roads gets bigger as you zoom out?

Comment: How to fix the position of circle when zoom out/in?